# How to reference Azure table data from a SQL Server table using a GUID

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-table-storage

I want to implement a chat feature on my site using both SQL Server and a Azure table.

I want to store chat metadata (like who's talking to whom and when, etc.) in my Azure SQL database and also keep a GUID of the chat in SQL Server, but the actual text of a chat stored in a Azure Table.

So, how would this work?

After reading about Azure tables, should I

1. store a GUID in SQL Server which represents the partition key in my Azure table?

   - so that all chats between user A and user B have the same GUID/partition?
   - then I can fetch all the messages by partition filtered by date!
   - would I need to use the row key in this scenario?
   - is there a limit on partitions, what if I end up having thousands or even millions?
2. Store a guid for each message, storing everything but the actual message contents in SQL Server, therefor leading to possibly billions of rows for all the chats. In this scenario I guess I would only use/need 1 partition?
3. ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general this will work.

1 - Yes using a repeatable, uniquely identifying key as partition key is what you should do

- The partition key can be a GUID. But maybe a hash value of User A&B's id would be better. Then you can still retrieve via partition key but it is not necessary to store it anywhere.
- Yes you would still need rowkey as this is the primary key of the record. Partition Key is just a grouping of certain records.
- The is no limit on partition keys - In general is should be something that re-occurs often but then should/may be thousands of them

2 - The billions of records will still be the case, depending on how you decide to store chat messages (store each chat line or after every x minutes or ...). But I would still suggest something like a Partition Key.

SQL Server 2016 and Azure SQL has a feature called 'Column Store Indexes' which greatly improves queries and optimizes the size of the data written to disk (Unfortunately this only available from P1 tier in Azure)

Have you considered using Cosmos Db - Throughput would be better. That is if you are going to have lots of traffic. Cosmos Db is very fast and if you use Partitioned Collections then you will have the same features and unlimited storage space.

I am sure you have good reasons but it is a bit odd that you want to use three different storage types for this. Won't a single storage type do (SQL, Azure SQL, Azure Table storage, Cosmos Db,..)?

Comment: Hi Van. Thanks for responding. I'm not going to use 3 different storage types, just two, I think, unless you know a better way. One table in Sql server (my primary db), which will hold a single row for each conversation between two people (ex. userA & userC, userD & userF, userA & userB) and hold the actual message in a Azure storage table, each row in Sql server will have a partition key as the unique id of the Sql server row. I don't know if there are any advantages to CosmosDb as I've never used  either Azure tables or CosmosDb, but I just need something that's cheap and fast

Comment: I'd try and store everything in a Azure storage table or a CosmosDB, but looking at the Azure table I only have a partition key and a row key. So I can't look up previous messages from different people, and I want to show my users a page with previous conversations

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. What you could do is keep a list of partition keys that is linked o the user and then search via those partition key's -  Searching via partition key is where your speed improvement lies. Then you can still use a composition of the id's of the user involved in the chat as the partition key and store that partition key against each user. 
Azure storage will be your cheapest option (and slowest). The question is Cost vs Throughput. In general I would try Azure Storage 1st and then 'upgrade' if speed is a problem. But partitioning is your friend here